# 'SQL Syntax error' while updating database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It shows this error: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''How I Learned Programming? ', blog_description = 'It\'s unbelievable! ', blog_c' at line 1 in /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/blogerist/vasilios/edit_blog.php on line 23

```
 if (isset($_POST['update'])){
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $description = 
  $_POST['description'];
  $content = $_POST['content'];
  $category = $_POST['category'];

 try {

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE cjv_blog SET blog_title :title, blog_description = :description, blog_content = :content, blog_category = :category WHERE blog_id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":category", $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":title", $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":description", $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":content", $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

}catch (PDOException $e){

   }
 }
```

Comment: `blog_title = :title`

Answer (score -1):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE cjv_blog SET blog_title :title, blog_description = :description, blog_content = :content, blog_category = :category WHERE blog_id = :id");
```

**replace with:**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE cjv_blog SET blog_title = :title, blog_description = :description, blog_content = :content, blog_category = :category WHERE blog_id = :id");
```

You forgot about **=** between **blog_title** and **:title**